# Ruby on rails array formatting - removing//selecting values from inner array inside a hash array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have long list of values in the inner_value field from which I want only some values

I have array in this format:

```
hash_array = [
  {
    "array_value" => 1,
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forFirst"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forFirst2"},
      {"Idontwantthis" => "some value"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forFirst3"},
      {"Idontwantthis2" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis3" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis4" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis5" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis6" => "some value"},
    ]
  },
  {
    "array_value" => 2,
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forSecond"},
      {"Idontwantthis" => "some value"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forSecond3"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forSecond2"},
      {"Idontwantthis2" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis3" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis4" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis5" => "some value"},
      {"Idontwantthis6" => "some value"},
    ]
  },
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "array_value" => 1,
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forFirst"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forFirst2"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forFirst3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "array_value" => 2,
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forSecond"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forSecond2"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forSecond3"}
    ]
  },
]
```

I have tried using running loop in this but its too much costly.

So I tried something like this:

```
hash_array.select { |x| x["inner_value"].select {|y| !y["iwantthis"].nil? } }
```

but this ain't working either..

Note:Order/Sort does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aim is not to `select`, you have to modify the input:

```
hash_array.map { |hash| hash['inner_value'] = hash['inner_value'].first }
#=> [
#     {
#       "array_value"=>1,
#       "inner_value"=> {
#          "iwantthis"=>"forFirst"
#        }
#      },
#      {
#        "array_value"=>2,
#        "inner_value"=> {
#          "iwantthis"=>"forSecond"
#        }
#      }
#    ]
```

Here you'd basically change the value of whole `hash['inner_value']` to what you want.

To do this with known key:

```
hash_array.map do |hash|
  hash['inner_value'] = hash['inner_value'].find { |hash| hash['iwantthis'] }
end # `iwantthis` is the key, that can change
```

For multiple keys:

```
keys = %w(iwantthis Idontwantthis)
hash_array.map do |hash|
  hash['inner_value'] = keys.flat_map do |key|
    hash['inner_value'].select {|hash| hash if hash[key] }
  end
end
#=> [{"array_value"=>1, "inner_value"=>[{"iwantthis"=>"forFirst"}, {"Idontwantthis"=>"some value"}]}, {"array_value"=>2, "inner_value"=>[{"iwantthis"=>"forSecond"}, {"Idontwantthis"=>"some value"}]}]
```

Comment: You did .first, I mean what if the index is unknown but key is known?

Comment: okay, also what if its multiple values, like suppose there is "iwanthis2" and "iwantthis3"

Comment: @user1735921 then you'd update the question to be precise from the beginning ;) But let me add if you'd want with multiple keys

Comment: @user1735921 see the update. You can consider making it a method, passing a hash and keys to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map`

```
    hash_array.map{|k| {"array_value" => k['array_value'], 'inner_value' => k['inner_value'][0]} }

#=> [{"array_value"=>1, "inner_value"=>{"iwantthis"=>"forFirst"}}, {"array_value"=>2, "inner_value"=>{"iwantthis"=>"forSecond"}}]
```